# Smack 4.1 Disable Auto Receipts

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I have just switch to Smack 4.1 from depreciated asmack. Smack 4.1 is automatically sending receipts with wrong id attached which is causing exception in my case.

Smack 4.1 is attaching 2 different id's with receipt

Here is the **chat message** received

```
RECV (0): <message from='***' to='***' xml:lang='en' id='65' kind='0' type='chat'><body>vhh</body><request xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts'/></message>
```

Here is the **received receipt** generated by Smack 4.1 in response of chat message

```
SENT (0): <message to='***' id='roZ7C-32' type='chat'><received xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts' id='65'/></message>
```

Smack 4.1 is attaching 2 different ids with **Received Receipt** **id='roZ7C-32'** and **id='65'**

My Question ares :

1. How can I make these 2 ids same
2. How can I disable the receipts so that I can generate my custom recipts

Comment: Smack's behavior is correct as far as I can tell. If this is causing an exception on the delivery receipts receiver side then it's a bug there.

Comment: Why is Smack attaching **2** different id's with a **Receipt** against a single chat message ?

Comment: There are **two** message stanzas involved, and every stanza has its own unique ID. The first message stanza with id "65" is acknowledged by Smack as delivered with the message stanza (id "roZ7C-32") send back to the sender of "65" containing `<received … id='65'/>`.

Comment: Can I make Smack to send id **65** of both stanza instead of **roZ7C-32**

Comment: No, that's not possible and also not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question , to get the ID of the sent message the code would be:

```
Message ms = new Message();
ms.addBody("EN", Messegeforsend);
DeliveryReceiptRequest.addTo(ms); //tells that you will need delivery for this message
String send_message_id= ms.getStanzaId();
```

and you can get the ID for delivered message which would be same as the ID for the sent message  :

```
deliveryReceiptManager = DeliveryReceiptManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
deliveryReceiptManager.addReceiptReceivedListener(new ReceiptReceivedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onReceiptReceived(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2,Stanza arg3) {
                String delivered_message_id = arg2;
}
```

});

the send_message_id would be exactly equal to delivered_message_id, so you would know which message has been delivered

Answer (score 0):

> SMACK 4.1.0 message receive listener  to write  below code

```
try {
                Message ms = new Message();
                ms.addBody("EN", "deleriyed");
                ms.setTo(message.getFrom());
                ms.setStanzaId(message.getStanzaId());
                DeliveryReceiptRequest.addTo(ms);
                connection.sendStanza(ms);
            } catch (NotConnectedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you can disable this is just not adding receipt to message when sending one:

Most important method is

> processPacketExtension

```
//Creating message in your method
public sendMessage(Jid to, String body){
    Message msg = Message(to, body);
    //Create and save your deliveryID to SQLite database
    deliveryID = DeliveryReceiptRequest.addTo(msg);
    ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).chatWith(jid).send(msg);
}

//Declare your stanza listener
private MessagePacketListener messagePacketListener;
//In your cotnructor   
messagePacketListener = new MessagePacketListener(context);

//Then in your login method register your stanza listener like this
public void login() throws SmackInvocationException, XmppStringprepException {
        connect();
        try {
            if (!con.isAuthenticated()) {
                ....
                con.addSyncStanzaListener(messagePacketListener, new StanzaTypeFilter(Message.class));
                ....
                }
        } catch(Exception e) {
                    ....
            }
        }



//Your StanzaListener where you parse your incoming message and if it is without body it is Delivery receipt
//Now you have your MessagePacketListener that process the incoming messages

public class MessagePacketListener implements StanzaListener{
    private Context context;

    MessagePacketListener(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }    
    @Override
    public void processStanza(Stanza packet) {
        Message msg = (Message)packet;

        //Message that have body
        if(msg.getBodies().size() > 0){
            //Text message
            //Do something with message msg.getBody()
        }
        else{
            //This must be sth like delivery receipt or Chat state msg and get your deliveryID
            processPacketExtension(msg);
        }
    }

    //processPacketExtension method that receive packet delivery ectension
    private void processPacketExtension(Message msg) {
        Collection<ExtensionElement> extensions = msg.getExtensions();
        if (extensions != null) {
            Iterator<ExtensionElement> iterator = extensions.iterator();
            if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                ExtensionElement extension = iterator.next();                
                if(extension instanceof DeliveryReceipt){
                    //Do sth with deliveryID
                    String deliveryID = ((DeliveryReceipt) extension).getId();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```